# Unable to bind data based on dropdownlist value and radio button value

Tags: c#, jquery, asp.net, gridview, datatable

I am currently trying to load my gridview according to the value in dropdown list and radio button.

However, whenever I add in the code to check for the radio button checked or not, the gridview will not load any data.

At first I thought it'd be the AutoPostBack that is causing the problem, however, after solving the AutoPostBack issue, I still unable to get data based on radio button. Every time I change my drop down list value and I change my radio button value, no data appears.

I am currently doing in C# and I am using my gridview as Data Table (a JQuery plugin)

Here's my sample code

ASPX

```
<script src="Scripts/jquery-1.9.1.js"></script>
    <script src="Content/DataTables-1.10.12/media/js/jquery.dataTables.min.js"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript">
        $(document).ready(function () {
            $(".gvv").prepend($("<thead></thead>").append($(".gvv").find("tr:first"))).dataTable();

            $(document).on("dblclick", ".gvv tbody tr", function () {
                var $this = $(this);
                var row = $this.closest("tr");
                row.find('td:eq(1)');
                var courseCode = row.find('td:first').text();

            });
        })

        function onPageLoad() {
            $(".gvv").prepend($("<thead></thead>").append($(".gvv").find("tr:first"))).dataTable();

            $(document).on("dblclick", ".gvv tbody tr", function () {
                var $this = $(this);
                var row = $this.closest("tr");
                row.find('td:eq(1)');
                var courseCode = row.find('td:first').text();
            });

        }

    </script>

<div class="row">
            <div class="col-lg-1">
            </div>

            <div class="form-group">
                <asp:Label ID="lblESTt" CssClass="col-lg-2 control-label" runat="server" Text="Test display: "></asp:Label>
                <div class="col-lg-3">
                    <asp:DropDownList ID="ddlTest" CssClass="form-control input-lg" runat="server" OnSelectedIndexChanged="ddlTest_SelectedIndexChanged" AutoPostBack="true">
                    </asp:DropDownList>
                </div>

            </div>
        </div>

        <div class="row" style="margin-top: 4%;">
            <div class="col-lg-5">
            </div>

            <div>
                <div class="btn-group" data-toggle="buttons">
                    <asp:RadioButton ID="currentOption" runat="server" Text="Current" CssClass="btn btn-primary active btn-lg" />
                    <asp:RadioButton ID="pastOption" runat="server" Text="Past" CssClass="btn btn-primary btn-lg" />
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>

        <div class="row" style="margin-top: 2%;">

            <div class="col-lg-1">
            </div>

            <div class="col-lg-10">
                <asp:GridView ID="gridView1" runat="server" CssClass="table table-striped table-bordered dataTable no-footer hover gvv" AutoGenerateColumns="False">
                    <Columns>
                        <asp:BoundField DataField="testA" />
                        <asp:BoundField DataField="testB" />
                        <asp:BoundField DataField="testC"  />
                    </Columns>
                </asp:GridView>
            </div>
        </div>
```

ASPX.CS

```
protected void ddlTest_SelectedIndexChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
           if (currentOption.Checked)
            {
                ScriptManager.RegisterStartupScript(this.Page, this.GetType(), "script", "onPageLoad();", true);
                loadCurrentData();
            }
            else
            {
                ScriptManager.RegisterStartupScript(this.Page, this.GetType(), "script", "onPageLoad();", true);
                loadPastData();
            }
        }

        protected void loadCurrentData()
        {
            gridView1.DataSource = retrieveBAL.retrieveCurrent(ddlTest.SelectedValue, DateTime.Now.Year);
            gridView1.DataBind();

        }

        protected void loadPastData()
        {
            gridView1.DataSource = retrieveBAL.retrievePast(ddlTest.SelectedValue, DateTime.Now.Year);
            gridView1.DataBind();

        }
```

> UPDATE

I've tried creating a oncheckedchange event for my radio button, however, the event just doesn't trigger. Here's what I've tried

ASPX

```
<div class="btn-group" data-toggle="buttons">
                <asp:RadioButton ID="currentOption" runat="server" Text="Current" Checked="true" CssClass="btn btn-primary active btn-lg" GroupName="currentPastOption" OnCheckedChanged="currentPastOption_CheckedChanged" AutoPostBack="true"/>
                <asp:RadioButton ID="pastOption" runat="server" Text="Past" CssClass="btn btn-primary btn-lg" GroupName="currentPastOption" OnCheckedChanged="currentPastOption_CheckedChanged" AutoPostBack="true"/>
            </div>
```

ASPX.CS

```
 protected void currentPastOption_CheckedChanged(Object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            if (currentOption.Checked)
            {
                loadCurrentData();
            }
            else if (pastOption.Checked)
            {
                loadPastData();
            }

        }
```

Comment: You need write on Change event for drop down and radio buttons.

Comment: @DipakThoke code behind? or jquery?

Comment: http://www.w3schools.com/jsref/tryit.asp?filename=tryjsref_onchange plese follow this

Comment: @DipakThoke have a look at my update, thanks!

Comment: Your code works fine. Are you doing something to the GridView and/or RadioButtons in `Page_load`?

Comment: @VDWWD i am only doing binding of datasource to thhe GridView in `Page_load`. Nothing to the radio buttons. The problem lies with `data-toggle="buttons"`. After removal of that, the `checked=true` attribute changes.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try with below code for the radio button group.There I have removed the `data-toggle="buttons"` and it works fine.

ASPX:

```
        <div class="btn-group">
            <asp:RadioButton ID="currentOption" runat="server" CssClass="btn btn-primary active btn-lg" Text="Current" GroupName="timeSelector" OnCheckedChanged="timeSelector_CheckedChanged" AutoPostBack="true" />
            <asp:RadioButton ID="pastOption" runat="server" CssClass="btn btn-primary active btn-lg" Text="Past" GroupName="timeSelector" OnCheckedChanged="timeSelector_CheckedChanged" AutoPostBack="true"/>
        </div>
```

ASPX.cs

```
protected void timeSelector_CheckedChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    if (currentOption.Checked)
    {              
        loadCurrentData();
    }
    else
    {
        loadPastData();
    }
}
```